# ScraperWiki: How to save html so it only gets loaded once

Tags: php, scraper, scraperwiki

When I execute a scraper, it loads the url using this method:

```
$html = scraperWiki::scrape("foo.html");
```

So every time I add new code to the scraper and want to try it, it loads again the html, which takes a fair amount of time.

Is there anyway to save the $html so it's only loaded the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said on FAQ at docs and help section of **scraper** wiki site:

> Yes, but all files are temporary.

I suggest you save the file(HTML or wherever is) with functions `fopen`/`fwrite` as you are using PHP.

source: https://scraperwiki.com/docs/python/faq/#files